# Webhook function does not execute

Tags: laravel, webhooks

I have this code to add user credit to a user when a payment is made

```
class Webhook extends Controller
{
    public function rave(Request $request){
if(Request::input('pay.type') == "credits" and Request::get('price') == 500 ){

 $credit = Credit::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => Auth::getUser()->id]);
$credit->increment('amount', 600);
$credit->refresh();

 }

}
}
```

The code works well when i try it as an ajax call attached to a button but it does not execute with a returned webhook response even tho it is returned with a `200 ok` when inspected with ngrok.
What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually returning anything. I'm not sure what kind of response you expect, but try returning something inside if block and see if that nudges you in the right direction.

```
if ($request->input('pay.type') == 'credits' && $request->input('price') == 500) {
        $credit = Credit::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $credit->increment('amount', 600);
        $credit->refresh();

        return $credit->amount;
}
```